# Angular ui router use different template based on environment

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to know if there is any way I can use different footer depending on the host.

```
        $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url : '/page',
        views : {
            "main" : {
                templateUrl : '/buy/product.html'
            },
            "footer" : {
                template : '<footer show-list="false"></footer>'
            }   
        }
    });
```

So let say if my current hostname is "test.domain.com" for example, I would like to set the show-list to true

```
      template : '<footer show-list="true"></footer>'
```

Any suggestion on how I can do that?

Comment: Had you tried using environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

If your footer has a controller you can simply reference a $scope variable from the controller in your template using either ng-if or ng-show

```
<footer ng-if="showList"></footer>
```

or

```
<footer ng-show="showList"></footer>
```

Then set the $scope variable in this case "showList" in the controller after checking the string of the current URL returned from "window.location.href".

```
$scope.showList = false;

var currentHost = window.location.href;

if(currentHost.includes("test.domain.com")){
    $scope.showList = true;
}
```

If your footer does not have a controller you maybe able to declare it inline

```
<footer ng-controller="yourController" ng-if="showList"></footer>
```

**EDIT**

If you need to do this in the router you can simply call a function you either create in the router or create a service with this function which you would pass to the router.

```
var isTestDomain = function(){
    var location = window.location.href;
    if(location.includes("test.domain.com"){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url : '/page',
    views : {
        "main" : {
            templateUrl : '/buy/product.html'
        },
        "footer" : {
            template : '<footer ng-if="isTestDomain()"></footer>'
        }   
    }
})
```

Alternatively you could create a service to use in the state config

```
angular.module('YourModule').service('locationSvc', function(){
    this.isTestDomain = function(){
        var location = window.location.href;
        if(location.includes("test.domain.com"){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Then call the function from the service in your template

```
template : '<footer ng-if="LocationSvc.isTestDomain()"></footer>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  It would work, however,  my footer is a shared directive which can use by other application so we can't set the $scope variable there.  The only way we can do is to switch between true and false in our route config.  Is there a way for me to check the current URL there and conditionally set to true/false?

Comment: This is possible in the route config. I have edited my response and added a new solution.